# Run system tests on Github Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, github-actions

```
- name: start Rails
  run: bundle exec rails s -e test
```

For tests the require a running Rails app, how do you start off Rails before running a system test (or Cypress test) with Github actions?

This action hangs..

Comment: Try the [`setup-ruby`](https://github.com/actions/setup-ruby) action